# How to change from AGIC Addon to AGIC via helm?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway

I had a AKS with AGIC addon enabled and I have to switch to AGIC as a helm chart (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ingress-controller-install-existing) in an attempt to connect two AKS clusters to a single Application Gateway but how can I change how AGIC was setup? I had though running disable addon would do the trick but when I tried to apply the helm-config file I was shown this error message:

`Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: Unable to continue with install: IngressClass "azure-application-gateway" in namespace "" exists and cannot be imported into the current release: invalid ownership metadata; label validation error: missing key "app.kubernetes.io/managed-by": must be set to "Helm"; annotation validation error: missing key "meta.helm.sh/release-name": must be set to "ingress-azure-1710484411"; annotation validation error: missing key "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace": must be set to "ingress-nginx"`

Also for some reason, I have to switch the Gateway's subnet route table manually when I connect it to one of each AKS's services which kind of defeats the purpose of being able to connect 2 AKS to the gateway, was wondering if there is a solution for that as well or a way to work around that. Thanks!

Comment: Use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ingress-controller-migration#migrate-from-agic-helm-to-agic-add-on as a reference and work your way in reverse order i.e. First, disable the AGIC add-on in your AKS cluster. This should remove the AGIC components but might leave some resources behind. Before installing AGIC using Helm, ensure that all the resources created by the add-on are removed. This includes the IngressClass azure-application-gateway that the error message mentioned. Now install AGIC using Helm. Replace helm-config.yaml with the path to your config file.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Is there a way to know what files are created when the AGIC was enabled? The cluster was created by someone else and I am not entirely sure what would be safe to delete other than the azure-application-gateway you mentioned.

Comment: List the resources in the kube-system namespace (or the relevant namespace if AGIC was deployed elsewhere) to see what might be related to AGIC: `kubectl get all -n <namespace>` Look for resources with names that include ingress-appgw or similar identifiers related to the Application Gateway or AGIC. AGIC uses ConfigMaps for its configuration, `kubectl get configmaps -n kube-system or if you have any specific namespace` Check AGIC-specific Service Accounts and Roles- `kubectl get serviceaccounts,roles,rolebindings -n kube-system or any other namespace`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transitioning from the AGIC add-on to a Helm-managed AGIC involves several steps because you need to ensure that resources created by the add-on are properly cleaned up or transitioned to be managed by Helm. The error you're encountering indicates that existing resources were not properly claimed or cleaned up during the Helm installation. As explained in comments,

*First, Disable AGIC Add-on*

```
az aks disable-addons --addons ingress-appgw --name MyAKSCluster --resource-group MyResourceGroup
```

*Second, Clean Up Existing Resources*

Ensure that all the resources created by the add-on are completely removed. This includes the IngressClass `azure-application-gateway` that the error message mentioned.

> Your question- How would I know what all resources got created when
> AGIC add on was enabled?

List the resources in the kube-system namespace (or the relevant namespace if AGIC was deployed elsewhere) to see what might be related to AGIC.

`kubectl get all -n <namespace>`

Look for resources with names that include ingress-appgw or similar identifiers related to the Application Gateway or AGIC.

```
kubectl delete ingressclass azure-application-gateway
```

AGIC uses ConfigMaps for its configuration, so check for that as well  `kubectl get configmaps -n kube-system or if you have any specific namespace`

Check AGIC-specific Service Accounts and Roles- `kubectl get serviceaccounts,roles,rolebindings -n kube-system or any other namespace`

and delete them after editing the namespace accordingly.

```
kubectl delete deployment <agic-deployment-name> -n kube-system
kubectl delete service <agic-service-name> -n kube-system
kubectl delete configmap <agic-configmap-name> -n kube-system
kubectl delete serviceaccount <agic-serviceaccount-name> -n kube-system
kubectl delete roles,rolebindings <agic-roles-and-rolebindings> -n kube-system
```

Once the cleanup is complete, you can proceed with the AGIC installation using [Helm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ingress-controller-install-existing)